# Verification: (Stationary points of) real-valued submersion on differentiable manifolds

Tags: proof-verification, manifolds, examples-counterexamples, fibration, scalar-fields

In the course of research, I made use of the following theorem:

> *Any fibre bundle over a contractible CW-complex is trivial.*

As a tangent to what I was actually using this for, I came to the following conclusion:

> Let $S$ be a differentiable manifold **not** homeomorphic to one of the form $A \times \mathbb R$. Then there is no continuous map $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is free of stationary points.

I would like my reasoning verified, as well as a non-trivial example where this might be a useful result.

### The Proof:

If we put a *continuous* scalar map on any differentiable manifold...
$$f : S \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
...then restrict the codomain to the range of $f$, we have a continuous surjection...
$$f : S \rightarrow \mathrm{Range}(f)$$
...which is a submersion *iff* $f$ has no stationary points.  For simplicity, let's assume that $S$ has a **single path-component**. This also implies that $\mathrm{Range}(f)$ has a single path-component due to continuity.

Now if $f$ is a submersion, then $S$ can be considered a fibre bundle...
$$F \rightarrow S \rightarrow \mathrm{Range}(f)$$
...where the fibre $F$ is (up to homeomorphism) the preimage of any point in $\mathrm{Range}(f)$. The theorem mentioned above implies that if $f$ is indeed a submersion, then $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{Range}(f) \times F$. Since $S$ is a manifold (without boundary, as this is not technically part of the definition), this can only be possible if $\mathrm{Range}(f)$ is an open interval. (Side note: I *think* this rules out all compact $S$ automatically since by continuity, these map into closed intervals.)

So it seems that the only case in which we can put a scalar function $f$ on $S$ free of stationary points is for $S$ which are homeomorphic to some product space of the form $A \times \mathbb R$. For $S$ with more than one path-component: well, if we can't have a map free of stationary points for even a single path-component, then we can't do it for the whole of $S$. It is only possible when each path component is homeomorphic to something of the form $A_i \times \mathbb R$, in which case the whole manifold $S$ is homeomorphic to $A \times \mathbb R$.

### Seeking an Example:

I cannot think of an example of a non-compact differentiable manifold that is not of the form $A \times \mathbb R$! Perhaps something of infinite genus?

Comment: For the example, simply think of a non-bounded plane curve (like $y=x^2$).

Comment: @paf - This is clearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$...

Comment: To complete your proof, I ask you one question: why does the fact that $f$ is a submersion imply that it's a fiber bundle? There is a condition of local triviality you have to check (or you may use Ehresmann's Theorem).

Comment: @paf - Good point! I thought I read this somewhere, but now cannot find it. I shall have a think about this.